# How to group and rowFilter a column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

my datagridview get it records from a database and looks like this:

```
[Country]     
  Gh
  Ng
  Sa
  Gm
  Sw
  Ru
```

I wanna now Filter this column using a combobox. I' ve two values in my combobox
Africa and Europe. My expectation is to get something like this:

```
//If i select Africa in the combobox
  Gh
  Ng
  Sa
// And if i select Europe
  Gm
  Sw
  Ru
```

That's my code so far:

```
private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            try
            {
                //Check an see what's in the dgv
          DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
          dv.RowFilter = "[Country]  LIKE '%" + combobox1.Text.Trim() + "%'";
          datagridview1.DataSource = dv;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
    MessageBox.Show("Column not found", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        }
```

How can i group them and implement it?

Comment: If what you want is to only show countries from what is specified in the combobox you could do it by hiding all other rows. To detect what ones should be shown you could add a row to the table with the same value's as the combobox has. and make sure each of the countries gets added to the one it is in. Then you show/hide rows accordingly

Comment: @maam27. Would u be kind a give me a practical example? I'm somehow new

Comment: I made a datagrid search in one of my projects so i should be able to change that a little for the example but in order to have it work you would need to add a new column to the database and have that called `continent` or what you would like to group them on. that column can be displayed if desired but it is the column that will decide if the row is shown or not

Comment: @maam27. Can' t i do something like using an IF Statement within the try section and instruct it look through the Country column and group the shortcuts into Africa and Europe? so that if i select in the combobox it just give me the related ones

The problem is that i get my records in the DB are too many. new column will be time consuming. [4 tables with over thousand record each ] :(

Comment: with a new column would be less code i suppose, but you could change the logic inside the foreach loop i posted as awnser to take a look at what combobox item is selected and based on that it could set know what countries to show and hide

Comment: @maam27. Thnx for ur help. I'm gonna try it and give u a feedback

Comment: You will have better luck using something like ListCollectionView which has a filter property that accepts a boolean method so that you can put all of your logic in there.  Then you bind your datagridview to the ListCollectionView, and the list filters itself.  This route offers much more flexibility and would allow you to select continents and then perform the logic of deciding which countries were filtered out based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  //search for identical value
  if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))//searchvalue would be set using ComboBox.Text
  {
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Visible = true;
  }
  //search for first art that contains search value
  else
  {
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Visible = false;
  }
}
```

It may not be completely correct since I had to make this quickly without compiler